# Regular Expression unix finding a string between < >

Tags: regex, unix, expression

I'm looking for a regular expression to find a string between < > in unix

for example

```
hello <en> this is a <test>
```

then I need to get as a result

```
<en> <test>
```

Comment: You could use grep: `grep -o '<[^>]*>'`

Comment: is it possible that the text will contain escaped greater than symbols that you would want to ignore? Example:  `\>`

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple:

```
(<.*?>)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gM3rB0/1)